# Delegate instances vs passing function directly

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, c#-7.0

I am curious as to what is the point of creating instances of delegates. I understand that they are function pointers but what is the purpose of the using delegate instances?

```
public delegate bool IsEven(int x);

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6,7, 8, 9 };

        // creating an instance of delegate and making it point to 'CheckEven' function    
        IsEven isEven = new IsEven(CheckEven);

        // using delegate for parameter to get sum of evens
        int tot1 = Sums(nums, isEven);

        // passing in the function directly as parameter and not delegate instance
        int tot2 = Sums(nums, CheckEven);

        // using lambda expressions
        int tot3 = Sums(nums, x=> x%2==0);

        ReadKey();
    }

    public static int Sums(int[] nums, IsEven isEvenOdd)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach(int x in nums)
        {
            if (isEvenOdd(x))
                sum += x;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static bool CheckEven(int x)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

At first thought opting to always use lambdas seems like the best idea if the functionality of the function you are going to pass does not have complex implementation, otherwise why wouldn't I just pass my function directly into the parameters? Also with Lambdas it is much easier to change it to compute the sum of odds as oppose to creating an entire new method as I would have to with delegates.

Comment: _"what is stopping one from just directly using the method as a parameter"_ -- did the code you posted above compile? it should have, and in doing so should have obviously answered that question as "nothing". It worked, so nothing stopped you. Frankly, it's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: At best, your question is primarily opinion based, but that assumes you already know that whether you use the `new` operator or just provide a method name, the same thing happens (a new delegate instance is created). The latter is just implicitly doing that, with the compiler filling in the `new IsEven(CheckEven)` for you. If you don't understand that, then you should focus your efforts on reading available documentation, as your question here would be too broad (SO isn't the place for a hand-holding tutorial on how programming languages work).

Comment: I suppose I should have asked what is the point of using delegate instances at all

Comment: OHH @PeterDuniho I see that makes sense I did not know that the compiler did that behind the scenes thank you that made sense.

Comment: Do you know what lambda functions are? You seem to be confused about delegates and lambdas.

Comment: Confused how? im pretty sure I understand them well enough to use them and manipulate them error free

Comment: @Cosmik11 - I think the confuse is that lambdas are just a syntax to create delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already used delegates even if you passed the method directly, the `Sums` method could not receive the method name if it's not set its expectation by the delegate definition.

Consider changing the delegate name to `public delegate bool EvenOddStatus(int x);`

you can send either your `CheckEven` method or this method:

```
public static bool CheckOdd(int x)
    {
        if (x % 2 != 0) // here changed
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

(of course you can use lambda here, but not in more complicated scenarios)

Now your `Sums` method can sum up either odd or even numbers based on the calling code (either pass `CheckEven` or `CheckOdd`).

Delegates are pointers to methods. you define how the code want the method to receive and return, and the calling code can pass a pre-defined implementation later, either a method or delegate.

What if your `Main` is another method that doesn't know what to sum, odds or evens? it will have a delegate from a calling code up the stack.